# Not able to cache templates and will be slow because of this notice

Tags: macos, phpmyadmin, xampp

Recently bought a Macbook Pro with macOS Sierra and installed XAMPP version 7.0.31.

After turning on MYSQL, ProFTPD and Apache Web Server, I noticed something when I opened phpmyadmin.

There was an error below saying:

```
The $cfg['TempDir'] (./tmp/) is not accessible. phpMyAdmin is not able to cache templates and will be slow because of this.
```

Answer (score 6):

[Probably, do you get an error like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkolf.png)

**The Solution Process:**

- First, stop xampp service; `/opt/lampp/lampp stop`
- Then, Go to the installation director of phymyadmin then find its "config.inc.php" file then add `$cfg['TempDir'] = '/tmp';` [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZQoa.png)
- At the end, start xampp service `/opt/lampp/lampp start`